# Basic : Return and stop code execution on JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I wrote these simple code,

```
function a()
{
    function b()
    {
        function d()
        {
            if (/*required condition goes here and should stop execution of
              function a()*/)
            {
                return
            }
        }

        d()
    }
    function c()
    {
        alert ('c')
    };
    b();
    c();
}
```

What I expected is the execution aborts when it meet the required condition on function `d()` and cancelling the execution of function `c()`. Otherwise, it runs the remaining function after executing function `b()`.
How can I do that?

Edit: What I actually want to know wheter if the 'return' key colud terminate immediately for the outer function like 'Exit Sub' on VB.Net

Comment: `function d` could return a value which you match later to then return if it matches an expected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd pass the information that processing should stop out of `d` and out of `b` and use it to determine whether to call `c`:

```
function a() {
    function b() {
        function d() {
            if (/*some condition*/) {
                return false;       // ***
            }
            return true;            // ***
        }
        return d();                 // ***
    }

    function c() {
        alert('c')
    };

    if (b()) {                      // ***
        c();                        // ***
    }                               // ***
}
```

Alternately, you could have `d` *throw*:

```
function a() {
    function b() {
        function d() {
            if (/*some condition*/) {
                throw new Error();     // ***
            }
            return;
        }
        d();
    }

    function c() {
        alert('c')
    };

    b();
    c();
}
```

...but then `a` would throw rather than completing normally (though you could add a `try`/`catch`). Also, throwing is relatively expensive and not for normal branching purposes.

Comment: So, it mean the 'return' keyword doesn't stop the execution immediately for the outer function, like 'Exit Sub' on VB.Net?

Comment: @BayuSadewa: `return` only exits the function you use it in, not its containing function. I'm 99.99% sure it's the same for `Exit Sub` in VB.Net when you use a lambda within another function (it's certainly the same for `return` in C#.Net if you use a lambda within another function).

Comment: OK now I see. I would use the value from inner function to determine whether to call remaining function on the container/outer function, am I right ? @T.J. Crowder

Comment: Thanks for your answer, nice explanation. That was the most closer to what I need to know. Anyway, how can i mark this question as solved? I'm newbie here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the return value for the inner function and use it as flag.

```js
function a() {
    function b() {
        function d() {
            console.log('in d');
            if (true) {
                return;
            }
            return true;
        }
        console.log('in b');
        return d();
    }

    function c() {
        console.log('in c');
        alert('c');
    }

    console.log('in a');
    console.log(b() && c());
}

a();
```

Comment: What does exactly `b() && c()` do?

Comment: it is a [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()) and checks the first expression and if it has a truthy value, the check the second expression. in this case, if `undefined` or `false` is returned, the evaluation stops.

Comment: According to snippet code above, what we got is `b()` return `true` from its inner function `d()`, and `c()` goes `undefined`, because`c()` never determined what it returned. So, the flag of `b() && c()` return false. 
Am I right? @ninascholz

Comment: b returns d and d returns undefined. `b() && c()` returns `undefined` from b and returns this value.

Comment: Whoa, i missed the `d()` Hahah.
So, what about the `alert('c')`. It never been executed.

Comment: you coud use `if (false) {`

Comment: Thank you for providing your help @ninacholz. Nice explanation.